# How to make a container migration with save and export

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

We have a project using docker containers through a docker-compose file. I'm trying to automate the backup and restoration of the current container state.

Thus I do the following commands:

```sh
docker save nodered/node-red > nodered_image.tar
docker export app_nodered_1 > nodered_container.tar
```

I then upload the tar files to the new server and proceed with the following

```sh
docker rmi nodered/node-red
docker load < nodered_image.tar
cat nodered_container.tar | docker import - nodered/node-red
```

I then execute `docker-compose up` and I get the following error:

> ERROR: for app_nodered_1  Cannot create container for service nodered: No command specified

I have tried also doing the following

```sh
cat nodered_container.tar | docker import --change 'CMD ["npm --no-update-notifier --no-fund start --cache /data/.npm -- --userDir /data --privileged"]' - nodered/node-red
```

And it gives me the following:

> ERROR: for app_nodered_1  Cannot start service nodered: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "npm --no-update-notifier --no-fund start --cache /data/.npm --

My docker-compose contains the following:

```yaml
version: '3.6'
services:
  nodered:
    # depends_on:
    image: nodered/node-red
    ports:
      - "8180:1880"
    restart: always
    environment:
      # define your tz here
      - TZ=Europe/Brussels
    volumes:
      # map your data volume
      - /var/app/node-red:/data
      - /var/app/certs-node-red:/data/certs
      - /var/app/ftp:/data/ftp:Z
      - /var/app/archive:/data/archive
```

Comment: You almost never do this.  Since you have all of your data mounted from host directories, it should be enough to back up the host's `/var/app` directory; even if you `docker-compose down && docker-compose up` it will still have the same data.  Don't worry about "the container" as an entity.

Comment: @DavidMaze I am aware of that sadly if I zip the exported volumes and transfer that half of my nodered / grafana workflows etc are missing. Also all the vsftpd files loose all permissions in the container for various users.